# automatic deletion of temporary files contents in Windows machine

Tags: powershell

I am using Windows XP. Now i am having some issue which causing my `PC` to run slow. So very frequently i was need to go and delete some temporary files from the directory `C:\WINDOWS\Temp` . Any way to get it done with a script automatically?

**Error**

I get the below error when I tried to run the script from my machine:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\rakshiar>D:\WIPData\cleanup.ps1

C:\Documents and Settings\rakshiar>powershell.exe D:\WIPData\cleanup.ps1
File D:\WIPData\cleanup.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts i
s disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details
.
At line:1 char:23
+ D:\WIPData\cleanup.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException


C:\Documents and Settings\rakshiar>
```

Thanks

Comment: The answer is right in front of you. Have you read the error message & done what it's instructed you to do?

Comment: who gave my post to `down vote`?

Comment: it wasn't me, but I'm guessing he/she gave it because your question was missing code sample that you've tried and which files in temp you want to delete(criterias).

Comment: Humm, I am done now. All are set. then someone who down vote me! That's not good!

Comment: remember that SO is a "library". this is not 'cased closed'. people with similar problem will hopefully search and use answers they find here before asking themselves. so since your question is unclear(ex. no criterias), it's kinda useless for someone else.

Comment: @Graimer Yes, what the issue was reflected in the description as I pasted. and The error resolution has been given by `Kayasax` , and I used it and my problem has gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this powershell script to clean up a folder on my windows machine. It's run via scheduled tasks; use something like this as the command "powershell.exe &'c:\psbin\cleanup.ps1'".

```
$dir = "C:\SomeDirectory"
$d = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
gci -recurse $dir | ?{ !$_.psiscontainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $d } | %{ remove-item -Force $_.FullName }
```

This deletes files older than one day. Change the AddDays to change this.

Comment: I just ran it from my `Notepad++` Run command. So how would I know if it is running or not?

Answer (score 5):

you have to change your executionPolicy ( by default powershell not allow to run script), so strart powershell as administrator and run :
`Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned`